# getting the id of the clicked element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onload = function () {

boxElement = document.getElementById('button1_id'),
boxMove = document.getElementById('button2_id');

if (boxElement) {
boxElement.addEventListener('click', function () {

    var boxLeftPos = boxMove.offsetLeft,
        rightper = boxMove.offsetRight;

    if (boxLeftPos > 0) {
        direction = (boxMove.offsetWidth - 50)*-1;
        boxMove.style.left = (direction) + 'px';
    }

    if (boxLeftPos < 1) {
        direction = 10;
        boxMove.style.right = (rightper) + '%';
        boxMove.style.left = '';
    }

});
}
};
```

I would like to fetch a button id of the clicked button and use it further on in the code, so instead of the naming the id´s

```
boxElement = document.getElementById('button1_id'),
boxMove = document.getElementById('button2_id');
```

i would like to get them with the js.

Comment: Aber du get them with JS

Comment: i meant, i want to get the id´s after they are clicked

Comment: @user2615859 - Use **`$(this).attr('id');`** for getting `ID` of the current element.

Comment: Could you show the relevant HTML? And explain the expected interaction(s), and which elements should be clicked to reveal their `id`s?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$('.boxElementClass').click(function(event){
    var clickedElementId = $(event.target.id);
});
```

add boxElementClass to all your elements, and the id of the clicked element will be stored in clickedElementId.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `var clickedElementId = event.target.id;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen all clicks via `document`

```
function makeYourMove(boxMove) {

    var boxLeftPos = boxMove.offsetLeft,
        rightper = boxMove.offsetRight;

    if (boxLeftPos > 0) {
        direction = (boxMove.offsetWidth - 50)*-1;
        boxMove.style.left = (direction) + 'px';
    }

    if (boxLeftPos < 1) {
        direction = 10;
        boxMove.style.right = (rightper) + '%';
        boxMove.style.left = '';
    }

}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var element;

  element = event.target;

  if (element.id === 'button1_id') {
    boxMove = document.getElementById('button2_id');

    makeYourMove(boxMove);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you add an example how to rewrite the code. Thanks

Comment: I've updated example. Something like this, if i get your question properly